# Como que eu conto a quantidade de itens de um campo repetidos?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, delphi-7

Tenho uma tabela com o campo CtrlCargaNum que possui o registro do numero da carga de um caminhão. Preciso fazer uma consulta que traga o total desse campo. Até que consegui fazer a consulta vejam:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) CtrlCargaNum 
FROM CTRL_CARGA 
WHERE CtrlCargaData BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-04' AND EmpCod = '01.01'
```

Só que ele conta somente os registros que estão nestas datas.

Gostaria que ele pegasse o número da carga que se repete e contasse como 1 CARGA

```
Ex: 
CtrlCargaNum = 1001
CtrlCargaNum = 1001

 = 1 CARGA

CtrlCargaNum = 1002
CtrlCargaNum = 1002
CtrlCargaNum = 1002

 = 1 CARGA
```

e some estas cargas: 1 CARGA + 1 CARGA = 2. Estou usando o mysql server
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia fazer algo do tipo:

```
SELECT COUNT(c.CtrlCargaNum) CtrlCargaNum 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CtrlCargaNum FROM CTRL_CARGA WHERE CtrlCargaData BETWEEN 
'2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-04' AND EmpCod = '01.01') c
```

Answer (score 0):

As tags MySQL e SQL Server estão marcadas. Segue solução para SQL Server, mas o uso de DISTINCT também é válido para o MySQL.

```
-- código #1
SELECT count(distinct CtrlCargaNum) as Qtd
  from CTRL_CARGA 
  where CtrlCargaData between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-04'
        and EmpCod = '01.01';
```

Comment: Dá o mesmo problema de antes. Ele tem que mostrar 19 cargas mas mostra um total de 26

Comment: @FelipeMichaeldaFonseca Eu testei o código acima tanto no SQL Server 2017 quanto no MySQL 5.6 e em ambos funcionou. Vide http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/42138/1 e http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea2c5f5/2